# Creating simple stored procedure does not work for me on Azure portal DocumentDB "Hello World"

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I was trying to create the batch insert, but I am still unable to create the simplest stored procedure on the portal. I'm getting th error shown in the screenshot.

Please let me know what can I do in order to overcome this.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this with a non-partitioned (single partition) collection? The error appears to be related to using a partitioned collection.

Comment: Hi David, So there is something a little bit strange there, If I delete and create brand new SP and save it, it works. but, if I try to change the SP and save it, even with a different name, I get this error again. Not sure if I am doing something that I've should't done, or the message is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug specific to `replace` and `upsert` operations on stored procedures on partitioned collections - and so those operations are currently disabled. The `create`, `delete`, and `execute` operations all working correctly for stored procedures on partitioned collections.

The error message indicates that the Azure Portal Script Explorer is attempting to `update` a stored procedure - however, the vagueness "save" button obscures that this is an `update` rather than a `create`.

In the meantime, I'd recommend trying out DocumentDB Studio: https://github.com/mingaliu/DocumentDBStudio/releases

You'll want to use the `create` operation to successfully create a stored procedure on a partitioned collection, and a `delete` + `create` a stored procedure on partitioned collections to update the stored procedure body / logic.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Appreciate your answer.